# Linked List getting null point error on trying to access its data

Tags: java

I need to reverse the elements of a linked list for which i used the following code, however I get the output as
For Input:
5

1 2 3 4 5

Your Output is:

curr has data 1

1 
Expected output:
5 4 3 2 1

Code :

```
 Node reverseList(Node head)
   {

    Node curr=null;
    Node node = head;
    Node next=null;
    while(node!=null){
        next = curr;
        curr = node;
        System.out.println("curr has data " + node.data);
        curr.next = next; 

        node = node.next;
        //System.out,println(node.data)

    }
    return curr;

   }
```

When i try to print the data after changing node to node.next it gives nulll point error!
p.s. this is a functional problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`node` is actually `null` after one iteration.

I commented some of your code to explain :

```java
Node reverseList(Node head) {
 Node curr = null;
 Node node = head;
 Node next = null;
 while (node) {
  next = curr; // Here, curr is null, so next = null
  curr = node;
  System.out.println("curr has data " + node.data);
  curr.next = next; // You are here doing 'curr.next = null' (see before)

  node = node.next;
 }
 return curr;
}
```

Here is a solution from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reverse-a-linked-list/ to reverse a Linked List :

```java
Node reverse(Node node) {
 Node prev = null;
 Node current = node;
 Node next = null;
 while (current != null) {
  next = current.next;
  current.next = prev;
  prev = current;
  current = next;
 }
 node = prev;
 return node;
}
```

By the way, if you haven't yet, have a look at the `ArrayList` object, which allows you to browse your list backwards too.

Comment: but I am also assigning curr = node and node cannot be null inside the loop

Comment: @Denise You are, indeed, but your `curr = node` is **after** the `next = curr`, so `next` takes the value of `curr` before it stops being `null`.

Comment: But that is what i Intended.. I am reversing the list so i want 1 to point to null instead of 2 . 
in the sense i want it to be 5->4->3->2->1->nulll

Comment: @Denise I edited my post to add an implementation of a solution :)

Comment: Thanks @The Coding Penguin, I have seen this implementation. I just didn't know where i was going wrong conceptually..thanks either way

Comment: @Denise You can also create a new List, to which you will add elements of the first one, one after the other. This should basically create a reversed clone. It's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with assigning the current and next values

```
Node reverseList(Node node) { 
    Node prev = null; 
    Node current = node; 
    Node next = null; 
    while (current != null) { 
        next = current.next; 
        current.next = prev; 
        prev = current; 
        current = next; 
    } 
    node = prev; 
    return node; 
}
```

Comment: I see what you did here..you are using the same nodes and changing the links..however I was trying to create a new chain... without touching the original one..is my approach wrong?